# Transform invalid JSON payload into valid JSON

Tags: json, text, dataweave, mulesoft

I have been trying to transform a wrong json format into a correct format but I seem cant figure i out since as far as I know its impossible. This is the wrong JSON format

```
{
"Name":Project123
"time": "2023-10-04T09:54:29.461Z",
"data": {
    "ALAM": [
        {
            
            "CLEARINGLINEITEM": "000001",
            "BURP": [
                {
                    "CLAIMNO": "52798",
                    "SYSTEM": "Test123"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "ALAM": [
        {
            
            "CLEARINGLINEITEM": "000002",
            "BURP": [
                {
                    "CLAIMNO": "52798",
                    "SYSTEM": "Test1234"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I did transform it to text first but since there can be multiple object inside ACDOCA, im not sure how it gonna map.This is how i want it to be:

```
    {
  "Name": "Project123",
  "time": "2023-10-04T09:54:29.461Z",
  "data": {
    "ACDOCA": [
      {
        "CLEARINGLINEITEM": "000001",
        "BURP": [
          {
            "CLAIMNO": "52798",
            "SYSTEM": "Test123"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "CLEARINGLINEITEM": "000002",
        "BURP": [
          {
            "CLAIMNO": "52798",
            "SYSTEM": "Test1234"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Really appreciate ur insights, thanks

Comment: May I know from where you are getting the wrong format. I do not think there is any way you can do it using Dataweave.In First place there should not be anyone who can send the wrong json format.

Comment: From a client, they send me a wrong format. So right now im just finding ways if its possible for me to fix the payload by using dataweave @HarshaShivamurthy

Comment: I would suggest you to ask your client to send it in the correct format. Do you have any idea why they are sending it in a wrong format?

Comment: The input is not valid JSON so DataWeave will not accept it. No JSON parsing library will accept it either. There is nothing that can be done until the input is valid. Maybe it is not JSON but some custom format that your client uses that is very similar. Only the one who created it can answer that.

Comment: Where does this payload originate from? What is the source system? Your input payload doesn't appear to be in valid JSON structure.